# Android ProgressBar setProgress() doesn't work as intended

Tags: android, progress-bar

I'm working on a progress bar that shows the rating of a game.
Here an example [CorrectGameRatingProgressBar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEd8Z.jpg).

Here's the code

```
  ProgressBar userRatingProgressBar = root.findViewById(R.id.users_rating);
  userRatingProgressBar.setProgress(0);
  ...
  // game ratings
  if (game.getRatingCount() > 0) {
      userRatingProgressBar.setProgress((int) game.getRating());
      gameUsersRatingText.setText(String.valueOf((int) game.getRating()));
  } else {
      userRatingProgressBar.setProgress(0);
      gameUsersRatingText.setText("N/A");
  }
  ...
```

It works well except for a thing: sometimes seems that **setProgress(0)** doesn't update the progress bar when I switch from a game to another that doesn't have a rating as shown here [IncorrectGameRatingProgressBar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXqpU.jpg). I even tried to set the progress bar to 0 before the *"null check"* but this thing happens anyway.

I tried this on a Xiaomi Mi9T with MIUI 12.0.5 (Android 10 QKQ1.190825.002) and on the Pixel 2 emulated on Android Studio with Android 11

Is there a way to fix this problem? If you need more infos, don't bother asking!
Thank you for all

---

I leave you down here the layout *layout.xml* of the activity

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/user_rating_text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="?attr/GameDetailTextColor"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/users_rating"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/users_rating"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/users_rating"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/users_rating"
                    tools:text="60" />

                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/users_rating"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:indeterminateOnly="false"
                    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/rating_circle"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    tools:progress="60" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and the drawable *custom_progress_bar.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thicknessRatio="16"
            android:useLevel="false">
            <solid android:color="?attr/SearchBarBackgroundColor" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="270"
            android:toDegrees="270">
            <shape
                android:innerRadiusRatio="3.1"
                android:shape="ring"
                android:thicknessRatio="12"
                android:useLevel="true">
                <solid android:color="@color/orange_700" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

---

EDIT:
here's the code of the java fragment:

```
public class GameDetailFragment extends Fragment {
    ...
    private long gameId = 0;
    
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_game_detail, container, false);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            gameId = getArguments().getLong("GAME_ID");
        }
    GameDetailViewModelFactory viewModelFactory = ((MainActivity) requireActivity()).getAppContainer().gameDetailViewModelFactory;
    mViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelFactory).get(GameDetailViewModel.class);
    ...
    ProgressBar userRatingProgressBar = root.findViewById(R.id.users_rating);
    userRatingProgressBar.setProgress(0);
    if (gameId != 0) {
    ...
    // game ratings
                if (game.getRatingCount() > 0) {
                    userRatingProgressBar.setProgress((int) game.getRating());
                    gameUsersRatingText.setText(String.valueOf((int) game.getRating()));
                } else {
                    userRatingProgressBar.setProgress(0);
                    gameUsersRatingText.setText("N/A");
                }
    ...
    return root;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe it's a coincidence, but in the cases that the progress value is wrong, is the same as the other progress bar value? It's just some random value? Or the value from the game before?

Comment: The wrong progress bar value is the same value of the game shown before

Comment: Can you share the context of the java code? I.e. what method it's in, what calls that method, etc. Also - just in case - can you confirm you're 100% sure the code in the "else" block is being hit when you "switch to a game that doesn't have a rating"?

Comment: If it's the same as the game shown before, then you are setting your data wrong, or looping through it wrongly,

Comment: I added the java code of the GameDetail. 
I already debugged it several times: in the debugger I see the right rating number and the progress bar also has the right number: it's just the progress that doesn't get updated.
It can't be wrong data just because this sometimes works and sometimes doesn't.
No loop in the code

Comment: It seems that if your getArguments() return null - than you will see data for the previous game. Try adding else block to this check with Log message to see if that is the case.

Comment: getArguments() works fine and it's not releated to the rating at all. 
While debuggin ,I see the actual number (if a game has 0 ratings, i set the progress bar to 0). So at the end of the call, rating is setted to 0 but the progress bar is stucked as before.
Progress bar are not called anymore in the code, just there and i'm using the method from ProgressBar.java
So, at

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find a solution!
Apparently I didn't set up the progress bar into the layout.xml
So, if you add `android:progress="1"` in the xml, the progress bar is getting updated everytime.